# How does the functor $\text{op}$ assign values to maps?

Tags: category-theory

This has confused me before and now that I'm studying it again it still confuses me.  There is a functor $\text{op}: C \to C^{op}$ for any category $C$.  I have $\text{op} : \text{Hom}_C(X,Y) \to \text{Hom}_{C^{op}}(\text{op}(X), \text{op}(Y)) = \text{Hom}_{C^{op}}(X,Y) = \text{Hom}_C(Y,X)$ so as you can see, I don't quite understand how it should work.  For instance in the category $R$-Mod, how can you assign to a morphism in $\text{Hom}_C(X,Y)$ a morphism of $\text{Hom}_C(Y,X)$ since they are two possibly very different beasts and not compatible in that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that composition in the op category has a different meaning.  Remember that a Category is defined by its objects, morphisms, and the composition of those morphisms.  In the op category, we have the same objects and the same morphisms, but composition has been redefined.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
$In particular: suppose that we have objects $X,Y,Z$, $g \in \Hom(X,Y) = \Hom_{C^{op}}(Y,X),$ $f \in \Hom(Y,Z) = \Hom_{C^{op}}(Z,Y)$, and that $C$ has the composition $\circ_{C}$. Then we define composition in the op category by
$$
g \circ_{C^{op}} f := f \circ_{C} g
$$
So, if in the original category we have
$$
X \xrightarrow{g}Y \xrightarrow f Z
$$
Then this is simply "redrawn" in the op category as
$$
Z \xrightarrow{f}Y \xrightarrow g X
$$

Comment: So where is the error in my argument though?

Comment: Ah, I found it.  op is a *contravariant* functor.  This means that
$$
\text{op} : \text{Hom}_C(X,Y) \to \text{Hom}_{C^{op}}(\text{op}(Y), \text{op}(X))
$$